# UITapGestureRecognizer on navigationItem.titleView not working on iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

The below code is working fine in iOS 10 and below. I recently installed Xcode 9.0 beta 5 and installed iOS 11 beta 7 on iPad Air for testing. Now the remedyMenuTapped method doesn't get executed.

```
self.remedyMenuView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("RemedyMenu", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as? RemedyMenu
self.remedyMenuView?.isHidden = true
self.navigationItem.titleView = remedyMenuView;
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RemedyDetailVC.remedyMenuTapped(_:)))
self.remedyMenuView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Comment: It's possible require tapGesture.delegate = self? or for prevent gestures conflicts, this delegate method extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
  
  func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
  
}, or maybe .isUserInteractionEnabled on custom View

Comment: Gesture will not work if you hide a view, set isHidden to "false", try it.

Comment: @AshokKumarReddyPolu  That I'm doing on viewDidLoad then on viewDidAppear self.remedyMenuView?.isHidden = false And user interaction is enabled in RemedyMenu in xib.

Comment: Please check frame of  your "self.remedyMenuView" and apply backgroundColor to the view, so u can easily find the view frame.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same issue with a custom view with a gesture on it placed in the title view, it looks like is a bug with xcode 9 or something changed in titleview for ios 11 that is making that whatever is inside the titleView has a size of 0, 0, I solved it by overriding the intrinsicContentSize property of my custom view, in your case "remedyMenuView" like so

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 150, height: 36)
    }
```

good luck.

Comment: I wasted five hours for this, this solved my problem

Comment: Dude! This is genius. Solved the problem for me.

Comment: a year later... using Xcode 10.1, the bug still exists but overriding intrinsicContentSize does the trick indeed.

Comment: Hello form 2022) Thank you for this answer)) I had a bug, where leftBarButtonItem with custom view with button inside it didn't get a touchEvent. And it Helps)))